# Are we feeling the sun's heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, sun

If I may summarize something I told a friend in a pub...

"We don't get heat from the sun at all. Heat requires matter to move through and there's too much vacuum between the sun and us for any heat to get here. What we get from the sun is light - photons - and some of those photons become heat when they fall on the Earth's surface. The sun could be might very well be terribly cold, but as long as it emits the same amount of light in the same frequencies, we'd never notice."

It seems to make sense to my lay-person mind, but am I in any sense right? What am I actually feeling when I feel warmed-up by the sun?

Comment: temperature can be defined as speed of atomic oscillations, so you can say that heat does not travel from sun. I think you may even go further: sunlight is absorbed by atmosphere but mostly by the earth surface itself. Here a nice paragraph on the topic: http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=804

Comment: So how would the sun emit photons if it wasn't hot? Check This](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation).

Comment: Heat is radiation. Radiation can be described as photons. In some sense they are the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a physics lab there is a (more or less) unambiguous definition of the word *heat*.   In a pub there is not.  In general usage, the word can mean different things.  For example, it might mean "thermal energy".   It might mean "thermal energy transfered by conduction".  It might mean "infrared radiation".

From context, I think you have taken the second of those definitions.  However, the chap that just bought you a pint might take the third definition.

I think the words are getting in the way of understanding here, and the wise course of action would be to avoid the word completely:   In your line of reasoning, you imagine energy being transferred by radiation from the sun to the earth, and then converted to thermal energy when hitting the atmosphere.   Then you can go on discussing *physics* and not *the meaning of words*.

Answer (score 1):

they are 3 ways to exchange heat : conduction, convection, and radiation. 
When we touch an object, the heat is transferred from the hot body to the cold body thanks to electrons collisions within the mediums. The speed at which this heat is transferred depends on the thermal conductivity.

The convection is a similar process that involves matter like air but with the difference that there is a flux of the air.

The last process is through radiation : the light that is sent from the sun travels into space and interact with the atoms when it hits the matter. Depending on the nature of the interaction part of it may be absorbed and converted into heat that will be stored by the matter raising its temperature.

Though the radiation coming from the sun results mainly in its blackbody radiation due to its very high temperature. Then if it was colder it would emit in slower range of frequencies(in particular in the red spectrum which is the color of dying stars). However, as long as the intensity is the same we would feel a similar warming.